# Group theory of quark model

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, group-theory

I am trying to understand the group theoretical aspects of quark model. In chapter 11 - Hypercharge and Strangeness- in the book titled 'Lie Algebras in Particle Physics' by H. Georgi, I am not able to apply the Gell-Mann Okubo argument to the particles transforming as a 6 of $SU(3)$. Can someone help me out with this?

The precise question in the book is as follows -

> What would the Gell-Mann-Okubo argument tell you about the masses of particles transforming like a 6 of $SU(3)$?